# Gradle: Keep transitive dependencies local to the imported library

Tags: java, gradle

In my project, I would like to use hadoop-hdfs-client, and I need Hadoop Minicluster for simulating the HDFS server in unit tests. Here is the content of `build.gradle`

```
implementation("org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-hdfs:2.6.0")
testImplementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-minicluster', version: '3.3.5')
```

However, by importing `hadoop-minicluster`, test cases will use `hadoop-hdfs-client` version 3.3.5. My question is: How can I keep test cases continue to use hadoop-hdfs-client version "2.6.0"

I tried some methods but not work

Method 1: adding `exclude`. test code still use version "3.3.5"

```
testImplementation(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-minicluster', version: '3.3.5') {
   exclude group: "org.apache.hadoop", module: 'hadoop-hdfs-client'
}
```

Method 2: Using `testCompileOnly`. Fail to compile

```
    testCompileOnly(group: 'org.apache.hadoop', name: 'hadoop-minicluster', version: '3.3.5')
```